# Trying to create a VM for virus downloading. Get an error when booting it up

Tags: virtual-machine

The error is this;
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Virus.

Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, have you tried to enable AMD-V? Did you find it in the BIOS?